# Load dynamically saved buttons from database

Tags: .net, database, vb.net, button

I really can't figure out how am I gonna code the flow.

```
For Each dtrow In camBtnDtable.Rows
    Dim cameraNumber = camBtnDtable.Select("ButtonName =" & " '" & "foo" & "'")(0)("cameraID")
    Dim nBtn As New Button

    nBtn.Text = "C-" & 'this should be cameraNumber e.g "C-01"
    nBtn.Name = 'select from the database, I don't know if this is still important though
    nBtn.Location = 'select x and y from database where name is this

    AddHandler nBtn.Click, AddressOf nBtn_Click

    picture.Controls.Add(nBtn)
Next
```

This is a messed up code, but, generally, what I want is to load the buttons' properties from an access database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim Btn as Button

' assumes the camBtnDtable is something Like Select * from buttons
For Each dtRow in camBtnDtable.Rows
    Btn = New Button

    Btn.Name = dtRow.CameraButtonNameColumn
    Btn.Text = dtRow.CameraButtonTextColumn
    Btn.Location = dtRow.CameraButtonLocationColumn
    ' or
    Btn.Location = New Point(dtRow.CameraButtonXColumn, 
                             dtRow.CameraButtonYColumn)

    picture.Controls.Add(Btn)   ' ??? picture?  not form?

    AddHandler nBtn.Click, AddressOf nBtn_Click
 Next
```

1. no idea of the column names
2. no idea of the db schema
3. no idea what all you have stored for the button (ie Location vs X, Y)
4. no idea why you are parsing name, the props should be stored as is and restored without processing

A single row will have all the data for a button though, so just loop thru the rows.

Comment: What does `btn` contain on the serialize code?

Comment: that was a mistake - it was going to be a part of a longer answer but I did not delete it all

Comment: I think I'm working my head too much. this is rather a simple answer. My bad. anyway thanks for always helping me.